# laravel passport not working in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.8, laravel-passport

I am trying to install laravel passport in my laravel 5.8 website to implement oauth2 and access token for API requests. I ran this command `composer require laravel/passport` but i getting error and i knew Latest version of Laravel Passport dropped support for Laravel 5.8, so i tried installing earlier passport version with this command `composer require laravel/passport:7.5.1` , now i installed but then when i run next command `php artisan migrate` i get following error -

> Migrating: 2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
> error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into
> `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) values
> (2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table, 2))

I checked database and saw only one table created *oauth_auth_codes*, After the error i did not proceed further with the command `php artisan passport:install`.

**So what steps i take to install laravel passport in my laravel 5.8 website with all required tables??**. So that i implement oauth2 server and tokens when request comes to my laravel site API endpoints. Plase answer with details, It's a tough project i am having right now.

Comment: Can you show your migration?

Comment: @sobir sorry what to show? i went to database->migrations folder and i don't see any file 2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table

Comment: Experts please.

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel 5.8 version, installing passport as per laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#introduction will not be completed. Things that you need to have for successful running of passport on laravel 5.8 , please follow the following steps:

1. Install Passport (you had did it already) using:
   composer require laravel/passport:7.5.1.

[image]

2. Now Before migration : put below code into composer.json as:
   "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*" .
   You can see in below picture as well.
   [image]
3. Now, You need to write in terminal as :
   composer update (now you are good to go).
   [image]
4. now, php artisan migrate.
   [image]
5. php artisan passport:install
   [image]

Thank you. I am sure it will work for you. :)

Comment: let me know Karu Roy whether it solved your issue ?

Comment: Still i got same error !. What does paragonie/random_compat package actually do? and running a composer update command updated many dependent packages which is risky too.

Comment: as i told above too that in laravel 5.8 passport cannot be installed directly following documentation. So That paragonie/random_compat package is mandatory to use passport driver. Its ok if you dont wanna go by composer update. You can simply use composer require paragonie/random_compat:\>=2 
for further info : https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat
when it is solved give me a green tick sir :) . Thank you

Comment: yes i know but i tested the way you said using composer update command but the error still appears!

Comment: you should do fresh passport intallation else you have other errors on your code